# Structure of multiproccessing Procceses in a large project

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Now we are a couple of guys that are coding a day-trading bots, but it's beside the point. The usual way of calling Process on a functions, gets nested and really obscure in already big classes that are well structured.

---

**The problem**

Let's say a Process may never terminate and writes output to a queue which we access in `def main()`.. Would this implementation be pythonic or following the pep20.. A good boilerplate?:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from time import sleep

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, q, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.q = q

def run(self):
    # doing work put work in queue
    self.q.put("hello foo")


class RestartingProcesses(Process):
    def __init__(self, ps=None,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ps_classes = {} if ps is None else ps
        self.processes = []

    def setup(self):
        """
        Initiate all processes that is in the dict all inserts into the list
        """

        for p, args in self.ps_classes.items():
            p = p(args)
            p.start()
            self.processes += [p]

    def run(self):
        """
        Uses the process.__class__ to instantiate and get appropriate args
         of process in the dict
        """

        self.setup()
        # should be while True:
        for i in range(8):
            for p in self.processes:
                if not p.is_alive():
                    print("worker dead")
                    p.join()
                    self.processes.remove(p)
                    p = p.__class__(self.ps_classes[p.__class__])
                    p.start()
                    self.processes += [p]
            sleep(1)


def main():
    q = Queue()
    processes_to_start_with_args = {Worker: q}
    r = RestartingProcesses(processes_to_start_with_args)
    r.start()
    r.join()
    r.terminate()
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

What are your experiences and have you solved it in another way?

Comment: Good implementation in exactly what sense?

Comment: Pythonic or following the pep20. A good boilerplate.

Comment: If your code works and has no issues, perhaps you should post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get the kind of feedback you want.